# Using file_get_contents with an array?

Tags: php, arrays, curl

A rather simple scenario; I've got an array of user inputted url's (could be any number from 1 to 1000+), and I want to perform `file_get_contents();` on all of them, and then if possible have all that binded/bound into a single variable, so that `preg_match_all();` can be performed on that variable to pick up specific strings.

I've heard that using cURL might be another option, however I've got very little knowledge on the function of cURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this sounds like a job for iterating over the URLs:

```
$urls = array('http://www.example.com/');
$allTexts = '';
foreach($urls as $url)
{
    $text = file_get_contents($url);
    if (false === $text)
        continue;

    // proceed with your text, e.g. concatinating it:
    $allTexts .= $text;
}
```

However if you have thousand URLs, take your time. curl offers to request multiple URLs at once ([multi request feature](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)) however, with thousands of URLs that does not scale as well.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I'm looking for. Any idea how I'd go about concatenating $text? I don't really understand what's returned by `foreach`?

Comment: @Fireworksable: `foreach` does not actually return something like a function. Instead everything you do inside the code-block is done, e.g. if you set a variable, after the block it will be set. I updated the answer with a buffer for all texts named `$allTexts`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) to apply function to every element of array

```
implode('',array_map('file_get_contents',$array));
```

Comment: This is a very simplified, fantastic answer.  Personally, I would have never even thought of doing that!  Learn something new every day.  Up voted